# Python UDP throughput is much slower than TCP throughput

Tags: python, docker, sockets, tcp, udp

I made two applications ('Client' and 'Server') written in Python.
On each of them beyond main thread I created two additonal threads, which are handling operations of sending / receiving data from each TCP / UDP parts.
So for client I have written code for:

- clientTCP part:

```
class ClientTCP:
    def __init__(self, host_address: str, port: int):
        self.client_socket = None
        self.host_address = host_address
        self.port = port

    def connect_to_server(self, is_nagle_disabled: bool):
        try:
            self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            if is_nagle_disabled:
                self.client_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, True)
            self.client_socket.connect((self.host_address, self.port))
        except socket.error:
            print('Error: probably wrong port passed for connection')
            sys.exit(1)

    def send_message_to_server(self, user_input: str):
        try:
            #print(f'MESSAGE TO SEND AS CLIENT TCP: {user_input}')
            self.client_socket.sendall(bytes(user_input, 'utf-8'))
        except socket.error as e:
            print('OVER HERE SEND MESSAGE TCP ERROR')
            print(f'Error: {e}')
            self.client_socket.close()
            sys.exit(1)

    def receive_message_from_server(self, buffer_size: int):
        data_from_server = []
        while True:
            byte_portion_of_data = self.client_socket.recv(buffer_size)
            if byte_portion_of_data.decode("utf-8") in ['BUSY', 'READY']:
                return data_from_server
            elif byte_portion_of_data:
                #print(f'TCP -> byte portion of data: {byte_portion_of_data.decode("utf-8")}')
                data_from_server.append(byte_portion_of_data)
            else:
                print('Entirety of message from server received')
                break
        return data_from_server

    def get_client_socket(self):
        return self.client_socket

    def __del__(self):
        self.client_socket.close()


def tcp_send_data_to_server(client: ClientTCP, data_to_send: list[int], size_of_buffer: int, is_nagle_disabled: bool, stop):
    try:
        #print('OVER HERE TCP!!!')
        client.connect_to_server(is_nagle_disabled)
        client_connection_list = client.receive_message_from_server(10)
        client_connection_message = ''.join([x.decode("utf-8") for x in client_connection_list])
        if client_connection_message == 'BUSY':
            return
        elif client_connection_message == 'READY':
            client.send_message_to_server(f"SIZE:{str(size_of_buffer)}")
        while True:
            #print("TCP!!!")
            if stop():
                break
            message_to_send = ''.join([str(x) for x in data_to_send])
            client.send_message_to_server(message_to_send)
            time.sleep(1)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Socket was closed due to some unknown reasons. Sorry. :(")
```

- senderUDP

```
class SenderUDP:
    def __init__(self, host_address: str, port: int):
        self.client_socket = None
        self.host_address = host_address
        self.port = port

    def connect_to_server(self):
        try:
            self.client_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        except socket.error as e:
            print(str(e))
            sys.exit(1)

    def send_message_to_server(self, input_to_send: str):
        try:
            #print(input_to_send)
            #print('OVER HERE 1 UDP send')
            self.client_socket.sendto(input_to_send.encode(), (self.host_address, self.port))
            #print('OVER HERE 2 UDP send')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error: ' + str(e))
            self.client_socket.close()
            sys.exit(1)

    def get_client_socket(self):
        return self.client_socket

    def __del__(self):
        self.client_socket.close()


def sending(sender: SenderUDP, data_to_send: list[int], size_of_buffer: int, stop):
    try:
        sender.connect_to_server()
        sender.send_message_to_server(f"SIZE:{size_of_buffer}")
        while True:
            #print("UDP!!!")
            if stop():
                sender.send_message_to_server('END')
                break
            message_to_send = ''.join([str(x) for x in data_to_send])
            sender.send_message_to_server(message_to_send)
            sleep(1)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Socket was closed due to some unknown reasons. Sorry. :(")
```

As for the 'Server' part:

- serverTCP

```
import socket
import sys
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime


class ServerTCP:
    def __init__(self, address, port, buffer: int):
        self.server_socket = None
        self.host_address = address
        self.port = port
        self.number_of_clients = 0
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.client_socket = None
        self.count_bytes_from_client = 0
        self.count_time_in_seconds = 0

    def create_socket(self):
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(self.host_address)
            self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server_socket.bind((self.host_address, self.port))
        except socket.error:
            print('Error: ' + str(socket.error))
            sys.exit(1)

    def start_listening(self):
        try:
            self.server_socket.listen(1)
        except socket.error as msg:
            print('Error: ' + str(socket.error))
            self.server_socket.close()
            sys.exit(1)

    def set_client_socket(self, client_socket):
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        self.count_bytes_from_client = 0
        self.count_time_in_seconds = 0
        self.client_socket.send('READY'.encode())

    def handle_another_client(self, another_client_socket):
        another_client_socket.send('BUSY'.encode())
        another_client_socket.close()

    def remove_client_socket(self):
        self.client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        self.client_socket.close()
        self.buffer = 100
        self.client_socket = None

    def get_server_socket(self):
        return self.server_socket

    def get_client_socket(self):
        return self.client_socket

    def get_transmission_data(self):
        return self.count_bytes_from_client / 1000, self.count_time_in_seconds

    def __del__(self):
        self.server_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.server_socket.close()
        print("Server socket closed")

    def __str__(self):
        kbytes, time = self.get_transmission_data()
        return f"TCP: {kbytes} per {time} seconds"

def tcp_get_data_from_client(server: ServerTCP):
    # data_from_client = []
    try:
        start = datetime.now()
        while True:
            byte_portion_of_data = server.client_socket.recv(server.buffer)
            if not byte_portion_of_data:
                break
            # data_from_client.append(byte_portion_of_data)
            string_data_from_client = byte_portion_of_data.decode('utf-8')
            if string_data_from_client.startswith('SIZE:'):
                temp = re.findall(r'\d+', string_data_from_client[5:])
                res = list(map(int, temp))
                if len(res) != 0:
                    server.buffer = res[0]
                    start = datetime.now()
            else:
                server.count_bytes_from_client += len(string_data_from_client)
            #print('End of the ServerTCP loop')
            time.sleep(0)
        end = datetime.now()
        server.count_time_in_seconds += (end - start).total_seconds()
        print(server)
        server.remove_client_socket()
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Socket was closed due to some unknown reasons. Sorry. :(")
```

- receiverUDP

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime


class ReceiverUDP:
    def __init__(self, group, port: int, buffer: int):
        self.group = group
        self.port = port
        self.socket = None
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.count_bytes_from_client = 0
        self.count_time_in_seconds = 0
        self.start = None

    def starting(self):
        try:
            self.socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.socket.bind((self.group, self.port))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(f'Error: {str(e)}')

    def get_transmission_data(self):
        return self.count_bytes_from_client / 1000, self.count_time_in_seconds

    def clean_transmission_data(self):
        self.count_bytes_from_client = 0
        self.count_time_in_seconds = 0

    def close_of_receiver(self):
        try:
            self.socket.close()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(f'Error: {str(e)}')

    def __str__(self):
        kbytes, time = self.get_transmission_data()
        return f"UDP: {kbytes} per {time}"


def receiving(receiver: ReceiverUDP, stop_thread):
    is_first_client = True
    try:
        #print('Start of ReceiverUDP')
        while True:
            #print('Before recvfrom, ReceiverUDP')
            #print(f'Start buffer: {receiver.buffer}')
            data = receiver.socket.recvfrom(receiver.buffer)
            message = data[0].decode("utf-8")
            print(f"Server UDP, message: {message}")
            if message.startswith("SIZE:"):
                temp = re.findall(r'\d+', message[5:])
                res = list(map(int, temp))
                print(f'New buffer: {res[0]}')
                if len(res) != 0:
                    if is_first_client:
                        receiver.start = datetime.now()
                        is_first_client = False
                    receiver.buffer = res[0]
                    print(f'New buffer assigned: {receiver.buffer}')
            elif message.__contains__("END"):
                receiver.count_time_in_seconds += (datetime.now() - receiver.start).total_seconds()
                receiver.start = datetime.now()
                print(receiver)
            else:
                receiver.count_bytes_from_client += len(message)
            #print(f"Message from Server: ")
            time.sleep(0)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print(receiver)
        print("Socket was closed due to some unknown reasons. Sorry. :(")
```

Static methods are of course 'thread' methods also.
Now back into the problem. I read on the internet that UDP transmission should be much faster than TCP. But that's not the case, in fact it's complete opposite for me.
When I put Server part on the container and run it + launched client with 'typed host_address' of docker gateway (it's something like 172.16.0.1') I got the same thing as earlier on running both on my machine.
On server application output I got such statistics for both TCP and UDP:

```
   TCP: 2.3kB per 15.004 sec
   UDP: 1.5kB per 15.009 sec
```

So clearly even now UDP is much slower than TCP. Why is that and what I did wrong?
I would be grateful for all advices.

Answer (score 1):

> Python UDP throughput is much slower than TCP throughput

This is to be expected. TCP is optimized for low overhead and will combine multiple `send` into as few packets on the wire as possible. With UDP instead each `send` will result in a single packet with all the overhead.

This overhead is especially noticable if the datagrams (i.e. the payload of `send`) are significantly smaller than the MTU of the link. And from a short look at your code it looks like that your are sending several small datagrams.

Apart from that it looks like you assume that a single `send` in the sender will match a single `recv` in the recipient. This is not true for TCP since data can be combined to reduce overhead: TCP is not a message protocol but an unstructured byte stream. The assumption is more or less true with UDP, but contrary to TCP there might be packet loss, packet reordering and duplication which you currently don't account for.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Steffen Ullrich.

So to say it simple I could only expect UDP to me more effective on 'traffic' with much higher throughput, for example if sent messages would have size of buffer for something like 100 000 characters?

Comment: @Hubertius: *"sent messages would have size of buffer for something like 100 000 characters"* - No, and such huge messages would not even work since the size of a UDP datagram is limited to 65535 bytes. The lowest overhead is if the payload + headers (IP, TCP/UDP) matches the [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) of the path, i.e. the maximum size possible without fragmentation. In general: use TCP if you need max throughput (like with downloads) and use UDP if you need minimal latency and can deal with packet loss (like with real time audio).